# Combine HTML Table Rows with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

Is there an easy way to combine rows in an HTML table where the first column is the same? I basically have a table set up like:

```
<table>
<tr><td>test</td><td>12345</td><td>12345</td><tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>12345</td><td>12345</td><tr>
<tr><td>test2</td><td>12345</td><td>12345</td><tr>
<tr><td>test</td><td>12345</td><td>12345</td><tr>
<tr><td>test2</td><td>12345</td><td>12345</td><tr>
</table>
```

and I want it to generate:

```
<table>
<tr><td>test</td><td>37035</td><td>37035</td><tr>
<tr><td>test2</td><td>24690</td><td>24690</td><tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is it generated from? Show us the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using jQuery:

```
var map = {};
$('table tr').each(function(){
    var $tr = $(this),
      cells = $tr.find('td'),
     mapTxt = cells.eq(0).text();

    if(!map[mapTxt]){
        map[mapTxt] = cells;
    } else {
        for(var i=1, l=cells.length; i<l; i++){
            var cell = map[mapTxt].eq(i);
            cell.text(parseInt(cell.text()) + parseInt(cells[i].text()));
        }
        $tr.remove();
    }
});
```

this is a "dumb" script -- no error handling for cases like different number of cells, fields being non-numeric, etc.  Add those if necessary.

Also, depending on how it's generated, it's better to do this server-side.

Comment: Again jQuery wins from standard JavaScript, it's a plague. If the OP wants to use jQuery, he has to tag his question with 'jquery'. And besides, please use the jQuery forums if you have **library specific questions**. Please ask about **real** JavaScript on this site.

Comment: @Midas - Chill.  I fully agree that people use jQuery far too often, especially on this site.  I posted the answer I did because it was faster to write, easier to read/follow and is a valid solution.  It can easily be extrapolated to normal JS, which was pretty much what your answer was.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a plain JavaScript version.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var table = document.getElementById('mytable');
    var tr = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var combined = Array();
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        var td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
        var key = td[0].innerText;
        if (!combined[key]) {//if not initialised
            combined[key] = Array();
            for (j = 0; j < td.length - 1; j++) combined[key][j] = 0;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < td.length - 1; j++)
            combined[key][j] += parseInt(td[j + 1].innerText);
    }
    while (table.hasChildNodes()) table.removeChild(table.lastChild);
    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');//needed for IE
    table.appendChild(tbody);
    for (var i in combined) {
        tr = document.createElement('tr');
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerText = i;
        tr.appendChild(td);
        for (j = 0; j < combined[i].length; j++) {
            td = document.createElement('td');
            td.innerText = combined[i][j];
            tr.appendChild(td);
        }
    }
}
```

This will work on tables with any number of rows and any number of cells. I suppose you want to make the sum for every column, that's what this script does.

And as cwolves mentioned, it is more logical to do this serverside. Users that have JS disabled will see the not so clean uncombined table.